# how to display 7 days of week weather forecast in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have tried this code many times. below code but getting Error.

this is the API used to get the 7 days week forecast. in below I entered the city "London".so I can get the 7 days forecast report of London.

```
http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?key=5742bec32f4141e08db171907171010&q=london&days=7
```

when I write the code in c#. instead of London, I passed the one textbox control.because
the country which I entered in the textbox.the particular country is 7-day forecast will be displayed at grid view.
 this is the code I tried

```
string city = txtcity.Text;
                string uri = string.Format("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?key=02d3de968c424e20b5a74149172409 &q=" + city + " &days=7");
```

I strucked at this point. I don't know how to pass the textbox name within URL.

the final result has to be displayed on the grid view control. I tried the code below. 7 days forecast will have to display on the grid view.

```
            XmlReader xmlFile;
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(uri);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
```

please, anyone, help me to solve this problem

Comment: you have a space character in the url, before '&q'... could that be it?

Comment: can you write the code

Comment: remove the space character and try again...

Answer (score 0):

I have came accross with something like that:

```
string city = txtcity.Text;
// string.Format("foo{0}{1}", "bar", "foobar"); the bracket {0} will be replaced with bar and {1} with foobar 
// General better instead of using string concatenation "foor" + "bar" + "foobar"
string uri = string.Format("http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.xml?key=02d3de968c424e20b5a74149172409&q={0}&days=7", city);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

// XmlReader is an IDisposable besure to dispose it
//using (IDisposable) makes sure, that the object gets disposed, when not needed anymore
using (XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(uri))
{
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
```

which results into:
[Grid containing the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRnUn.png)

Comment: sir. result will displayed only one row of the data grid view .have to get 7 days result

Comment: Well, thats because the data structure is terrible. You have several tables. You will need to merge all tables together.